# Key to boot from usb on ubuntu macbook air

Tags: macos

Recently I removed macintosh from my macbookAir and intalled on it ubuntu 14.04, I have been trying to intall debian during last week, but I don't have idea what's the key to enter into 'bios boot options' ... 
(to boot from pendrive).

came here for some help, thx in advance.

Comment: Not for StackOverflow, why not move this to AskDifferent or SuperUser?

Comment: Because it involves more than just apple knowledge, thanks for the suggestion I also leave a post there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nobody reply so, I figured it out by myself keep pressed 'alt' that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Start the computer while keeping pressed `option` key.